# How to find circles in 2d point set

Tags: java, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I have a set of 2d points. They are X,Y coordinates on a standard Cartesian grid system(they are represents a data from 2d laser scanner). I need to find the circles in that point set or their diameters. I tried Hough Transform and to look for straight lines with no luck. What is the best way to find circles or their diameters from point-cloud?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think that [here](http://archimer.ifremer.fr/doc/00033/14451/11752.pdf) you will find decent papers on the topic.